# Get State By Linearid corda version 3.1

Tags: corda

I am trying to get a state by lineaId by getting a empty list:
my code:

```
  val queryCriteria = QueryCriteria.LinearStateQueryCriteria(uuid = listOf(linearId.id))
  val customerAuditor = serviceHub.vaultService.queryBy<CustomerAuditor>(queryCriteria).states.single()
```

Error:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: List is empty.
at kotlin.collections.CollectionsKt___CollectionsKt.single(_Collections.kt:472) ~[kotlin-stdlib-1.1.60.jar:1.1.60-release-55 (1.1.60)]
at com.hsbc.auditorFlow.updateCustomerInit$Initiator.call(UpdateCustomerAuditorInit.kt:59) ~[cordapp-customer-0.1.jar:?]
at com.hsbc.auditorFlow.updateCustomerInit$Initiator.call(UpdateCustomerAuditorInit.kt:31) ~[cordapp-customer-0.1.jar:?]
at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:96) [corda-node-3.1-corda.jar:?]
at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:44) [corda-node-3.1-corda.jar:?]
at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.run1(Fiber.java:1092) [quasar-core-0.7.9-jdk8.jar:0.7.9]
at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.exec(Fiber.java:788) [quasar-core-0.7.9-jdk8.jar:0.7.9]
at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.doExec(RunnableFiberTask.java:100) [quasar-core-0.7.9-jdk8.jar:0.7.9]
at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.run(RunnableFiberTask.java:91) [quasar-core-0.7.9-jdk8.jar:0.7.9]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:1.8.0_144]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_144]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [?:1.8.0_144]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [?:1.8.0_144]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_144]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_144]
at net.corda.node.utilities.AffinityExecutor$ServiceAffinityExecutor$1$thread$1.run(AffinityExecutor.kt:62) [corda-node-3.1-corda.jar:?]
```

When i do get all states the state is present:

```
 val generalCriteria = QueryCriteria.VaultQueryCriteria(Vault.StateStatus.UNCONSUMED)
    var pageNumber = DEFAULT_PAGE_NUM
    val states = mutableListOf<StateAndRef<ContractState>>()
    do {
        val pageSpec = PageSpecification(pageSize = 200, pageNumber = pageNumber)
        val results = services.vaultQueryByWithPagingSpec(CustomerAuditor::class.java,generalCriteria, pageSpec)
        states.addAll(results.states);
        pageNumber++
    } while ((pageSpec.pageSize * pageSpec.pageNumber) <= results.totalStatesAvailable)

    return states;
```

Output of this:

```
      [
  {
    "state": {
      "data": {
        "linearId": {
          "externalId": null,
      "id": "d7b8331d-6a1a-408a-aff7-5c823e91c6e3"
    }
  },
  "contract": "com.hsbc.contract.PSContract",
  "encumbrance": null,
  "constraint": {}
},
"ref": {
  "txhash": {
    "bytes": "FbMJYu2K1lrqHLK4rkhOogn5r/u7iAa26AobmrtWDRY=",
    "size": 32,
    "offset": 0
  },
  "index": 0
}


}
    ]
```

(i have removed the participants and notary tag as they were very big , i had 3 participants)

Comment: use `listOf(UUID.fromString(linearId.id))` instead of `listOf(linearId.id))` let me know if it works

Answer (score 1):

I always use this:

```
inline fun <reified T : LinearState> getLinearStateById(
        linearId: UniqueIdentifier,
        services: ServiceHub
): StateAndRef<T>? {
    val query = QueryCriteria.LinearStateQueryCriteria(linearId = listOf(linearId))
    return services.vaultService.queryBy<T>(query).states.singleOrNull()
}
```

Comment: That is approx. the same as what i did but still facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

I faced this. Just check if the Unconsumed State vault which you are trying to access is present Participants list. If it is not present than it will not be queried and thus list will always be empty. Hope this helps :)

Comment: it is .. i am accessing both from the same node

Answer (score 0):

In Java I did this way...!
@nithesh / @jayant let me know if it works..

```
UniqueIdentifier linearId = UniqueIdentifier.Companion.fromString(linearIdAsString);
QueryCriteria queryCriteria = new QueryCriteria.LinearStateQueryCriteria(
                null,   // List of Parties for the state
                ImmutableList.of(linearId),
                Vault.StateStatus.UNCONSUMED,
                null    // Set of State types
        );

List<StateAndRef<YourState>> stateAndRefs = getServiceHub().getVaultService().queryBy(YourState.class, queryCriteria).getStates();
YourState yourState = stateAndRefs.get(0).getState().getData();
```